# Ruby match first occurrence of string for a gsub replacement

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub, string-substitution

I have a string let's say *http://someUrul.com/someController/SOmeAction?SomeQS=http://someOtherUrl*

and I want to replace the first http with https, but not the second, so I end up with **https**://someUrul.com/someController/SOmeAction?SomeQS=http://someOtherUrl

How can I accomplish this with a simple gsub?  The following replaces both.

```
request.url.gsub(/http:/, "https:")
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001185), not [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186). `gsub` is global, `sub` isn't.

Comment: Thank you! I'm...just getting started with RoR, and the language/framework is still a little uncomfortable...I'm a C#/JS guy.

Comment: At least you've seen the light :D